# Can I use existing figs as axs in a new fig?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have four scripts which create figures that use subplots via `matplotlib.pyplot` and `matplotlib.gridspace`. The axs are set up as follows;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(dpi=1000)
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=4, nrows=3, figure=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 0])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[2, 0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0:, 1:])
```

I'd like to create a new figure wherein the subplots are as follows

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=1000)
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=2, figure=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 0])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, 1])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, 1])
```

But each ax is populated using a script similar to the first one. Is this possible?

Comment: Its not really possible. I think the best way to get close to this is have a function which adds everything you want to one of those axes, with the first input being the Axes instance you want to plot on, and just call it twice, once on the first figure, and again on the second figure,

Comment: Matplotlib now has a subfigures functionality.  You can also access this via the subplot_mosaic method.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Should I be able to call a saved script (wrapped in main() I assume) as a subfigure?